# What is the purpose of defining the type of response of the observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

What's the difference between the three? Is there any advantage?

```
.subscribe((response: any) => {
                //do something
            });

.subscribe(response => {
                //do something
            });

.subscribe((response:boolean) => {
                //do something
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a type lets future you and other people reading your code get a better understanding of what they're working with. It also allows your code to be statically analyzed so you can get on-the-fly help. `TSLint` won't actually allow the second option above because you should really type things. The first option gives you no information about *what* your response is. It could literally be anything. This isn't helpful when you come back to the component and don't remember what it was that was in your response. The third option is the most *informative* -- it makes reading and refactoring your code much easier. Here's more information on types and why they help: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/why-typescript.html

Answer (score 2):

Typing parameters enforces type integrity. In this case, however, it's not doing much. A second order function like this should already have its parameter be implicitly typed via type generics:

```
let obx = new Observable<boolean>(observer => {
  observer.next(true);
  observer.next(false);
  observer.complete();
}

obx.subscribe(res => {
  if(res) { doStuff(); } // res is implicitly boolean here
  let fail = res.wontWork ; // Typescript error: property 'wontWork' does not exist on type boolean 
}
```

Angular allows many opportunities to type this parameter as a generic through its API, e.g. the `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 1):

What was said above is correct. It also lets you enforce type checking. You can read more about it here:
https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response